# How to make buttons (left,right) that constantly apply force to object while holding them down?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm making an android game. I have a cube that moves forward by applying force on it (so when i colide i get a better effect) so now i need help to make controls for android. I tried making buttons but i cant get them to (while holding it down) apply force to left or right constantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an OnTouchListener on the button. And start applying force when the user presses the button, which is ACTION_DOWN event, until user lifts his finger, which is ACTION_UP event.
You need to optimise for dragging and multi-finger.